# IndirectList not instantiated when using List but it works when using ArrayList

Tags: java, list, arraylist

i am facing some confusion when using a List or an ArrayList with the framework JSF 
I used to work direclty with a defined ArrayList :

```
@OneToMany
ArrayList<Book>books;
```

and in some controlers , i can do: `user.getBooks();` , i will get the elements of my list and that's good

but something different happens when i use List instead of ArrayList:

```
@OneToMany
List<Book>books;
```

if i try: `user.getBooks();` i will get : `IndirectList: not instantiated`
i can only get the list if i do : `FetchType.EAGER`

can someone explain me the difference?

Answer (score 1):

A framework might instantiate an ArrayList. But a List cannot be instantiated; it's an interface. Use List by doing something like:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "otherEntity")
private List<String> components = new ArrayList<>();
```

It's always a good idea to initialize the collection, either in the variable declaration or the constructor, to avoid NPEs.